# Can a bond ever be considered premium or discount if held to maturity?

Tags: bonds, maturity

I'm trying to understand bonds. I'm wondering if it is impossible to have a bond considered premium (or discount) if it is held for it's *full* maturity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bond is selling for more than its par value then it's sold at a premium.  If it's sold for less then it's sold at a discount.  Whether the holder intends to hold it to maturity or not is irrelevant.

If you're asking if a bond you already own can change from premium to discount (or vice-versa) then no, it matters what you bought it for.  If you bought a bond for $102 and now it's selling for $98, you bought it at a premium, so any accounting or tax ramifications of buying a bond at a premium should stay in place.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is such a thing as a 1-yr premium or discount bond if you bought and sold at par, and at maturity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, a bond bought at par is neither premium or discount, regardless of the length of the bond. Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve or are you just trying to understand terminology?

Comment: Just trying to understand terminology and concepts. A bond bought at par is neither, but can be sold at a premium or discount?

Comment: Correct.  Premium and discount just describe whether the bond is selling over or under its par value.

Comment: So _could or would_ a 1-yr bond ever be sold above or below its par value?

Comment: Absolutely - any bond can be sold at a premium or discount.  The market price depends on the coupons it pays and the credit risk of the issuer.  Whether you hold it to maturity or not (from your original question) is irrelevant.

Comment: @skube To add on to this answer, consider how a bond is valued: A bond will give the holder back a stated principal amount in a future maturity date, plus possibly interest payments along the way. If you compare a particular bond with the 'market rate' of interest, you can see whether the bond pays more or less than that market rate. ie: if the interest rate today is 1%, but you see a bond offering 2% interest payments, then that bond will give you more in payments than the $1,000 face value. This makes it worth more than a standard product [assuming it has same level of risk]...

Comment: But if market rates rise to 3% while you hold that bond, then your bond is now worth *less* than the stated $1,000 face value. This is because your bond no longer pays higher than the market interest rate, and therefore $1,000 could be better spent on another interest-earning investment. So, the value of a bond fluctuates with the market interest rate, until the date of maturity.